# regex to match only one upper case letter

Tags: regex

I need to match (must has only one upper case letter at least) if more than won't match.

```
    Kitty   || Valid has one upper case letter  
    wiDivb  || Valid has one upper case letter
    ikBVu   || Invalid more than one upper case letter
    welcmw  || Invalid No upper case letter
    A       || Valid has one upper case letter  
    AA      || Invalid more than one upper case letter
```

I have tried :

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]{1})
```

but it matches even it has more than one upper case letter and i want it only one so i've added `{1}` but it did not

Comment: Do you require at least 1 lowercase letter also? Or is `A` valid?

Comment: @Barmar yes `A` is valid too but `AA` is not valid, i just want to check against upper case letters (must be one and not more than one) that is why i've been thinking about `(?=.*[A-Z]{1})`

Comment: What about hyphens, diacritics and stuff? `^[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z][^A-Z\s]*$` will allow words with a single uppercase English letter but allowing any characters otherwise. If language specific I'd, being Swedish, add the uppercase Swedish diacritics i.e. `^[^A-ZÅÄÖÉÜ\s]*[A-ZÅÄÖÉÜ][^A-ZÅÄÖÉÜ\s]*$`

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJY4Ei/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - at least one lowercase ASCII letter after any 0+ chars other than line break chars from the start of a string
- `[a-z]*` - 0+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `[a-z]*` - 0+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Wouldn't `^(?=[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*).*$` be simpler?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness No, the fact is that there must also be at least 1 lowercase letter. See `(?=.*[a-z])` in the original pattern.

Comment: Right, I read the OP say `only one upper case letter at least` but then realized the third string was not supposed to be matched.

Comment: it works perfect, but what if i just want to check against upper case letters (must be only one upper case and not more than one) even `A` is vaid but `AA` is not, that is why i've been thinking about `(?=.*[A-Z]{1})`

Comment: @ShGurl `{1}` is redundant in every regex, it is the default behavior to match an atom only once. `ab` will match 1 `a` and then 1 `b`. It does not restrict anything, just "repeats" matching the quantified subpattern.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't require any lowercase letters, you can use:

```
^[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$
```

This matches any number of lowercase, followed by a single uppercase, followed by any number of lowercase.

If you require at least one lowercase, you can use an alternation to handle the two cases  where the lowercases are optional on the left and required on the right, or optional on the right and required on the left:

```
^(?:[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]+|[a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]*)$
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex uses 2 positive lookaheads which assert that there is at least one lowercase character `(?=.*[a-z])` and at least one uppercase character `(?=.*[A-Z])`. That means that there can also be 2 uppercase characters. Note that `[A-Z]{1}` can be written as `[A-Z]`

You might match your values without the positive lookaheads if only 1 uppercase letter is also allowed:

`^[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uTpvXT/1)

That would match:

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `[a-z]*` Match zero or more times a - z
- `[A-Z]` Match one time A -Z
- `[a-z]*` Match zero or more times a - z
- `$` Assert the end of the string